# So I downloaded a game off of a different account but I lost the account midway as a game was downloading (PS4)

Tags: ps4

I was downloading a game midway, then I couldn't log-in anymore and the game had a pop-up saying Corrupted File (CE-36244-9). I bought the game on a new account, would the pop-up saying "Corrupted file" still pop-up if I don't lose the account or would it do the same?

Is the problem with the account or with the hard drive, or with the game in general? I'd really like your inputs.

Comment: Have you tried to delete what you already downloaded and redownload it again? Also if you could name the game you are trying to download, it might help...

Comment: I've already tried that, but it still won't work. The game is NBA 2K19, I digitally bought it.

Comment: I found this, maybe that can help https://www.ps4storage.com/data-is-corrupted-error-ce-36244-9/.
On the PlayStation support site, they also mention contacting the support for more technical assistance https://support.playstation.com/s/article/CE-36244-9?language=en_US